# using this index calculated field to display marks by increment?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a calculated field which multiplies an index by increments in which I want my number of records displayed. For instance, if I have a bar chart with 30,000 records, and I want to display them as incremental square marks, then I would do a calc like this:

```
if index()-1 <= int(WINDOW_SUM(sum([Number of Records]))/500)
then index()*500
END
```

in this case, I want to have a single mark value represent 500 records.

when I lay it out, I put the calc in my columns, and the dimension in my rows, but it doesn't display anything.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Search for tutorials on making unit charts. Waffle charts also use similar techniques

Comment: @AlexBlakemore I have seen something like this, but to my understanding, regular marks cannot be used? I do not want to incorporate custom marks because it needs to fit in with the general theme of the other viz

Comment: What happens if you lay it out in a simple table? Do you get the expected value against each record?

Comment: @AndyTARSols I actually got it figured out, thanks!